# Prove that for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$ , $|a − b| ≤ |a − r| + |b − r|$

Tags: real-analysis

I have trouble understanding absolute value manipulation. I also have trouble finding out how to just have $r$ on the right side of the equation. I had the plan of using the triangle inequality.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Rewrite $\; a-b=(a-r)+(r-b)$, and use the triangle inequality.

Comment: Do you know about the triangle inequality?

Comment: Somewhat. I understand why  −=(−)+(−). It is unclear to me how I would apply the triangle inequality over the equation. In my real analysis class currently every step has been justified by axioms and lemmas. I understand that  a − b ≤ |a − b|, because I have proved it and how that is used to prove the triangle inequality. However regarding " −=(−)+(−)"  and using the triangle inequality, is a bit hazy

Comment: @EverOlivares The triangle inequality for any real $x,y$ is that $|x+y|\le |x|+|y|.$ To use this to prove your inequality, just take $x=a-r,y=-(b-r).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always have $|x|= \max(x,-x)$ and $x \le |x|$, so

$a-b \le a-r+r-b \le |a-r| + |r-b|$.

Similarly,
$b-a \le b-r+r-a \le |r-b|+|a-r|$.

Comnbining gives the desired result.

Comment: Great!! since I have shown (a-b) and -(a-b), thus |a − b|.Would I just state in my proof that |b − r|=|r − b| is valid by the definition of absolute value? Your response was very comprehensive!

Comment: It depends on how much detail you want. Since $|x| = \max(x,-x)$ we see that $|x|=|-x|$.

Answer (score 0):

Here all you need about absolute value

$$(\forall x,y) \in \Bbb R^2)$$

$$|x|\ge 0$$

$$|x|=0 \iff x=0$$

$$|x|=|-x|$$

$$|x+y|\le |x|+|y|$$
$$|x-y|\le |x|+|y|$$

So replace, in the last,

$x $ by $ a-r $ and $ y $ by $ b-r$.

Comment: regarding the question if I let x=a-r and y=b-r ,thus  x-y= a-2r-b. Thus to correct, y=b+r. when applying to the right hand side of the inequality how would I proof that |b − r|=|r − b|

Comment: @EverOlivares No $x-y=a-b$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the triangular inequality: $|a-b|=|a-r+r-b|\le |a-r|+|r-b|=|a-r|+|b-r| $.

Comment: Thank you! I love the simplicity of your response.

Answer (score 0):

$(a-b)=(a-r)+(r-b)$.
By the triangle inequality,
$|a-b| \leq |a-r|+|r-b|$
As $|r-b|$ = $|b-r|$
(Because  for any real numbers r,b, if $r,b$ then $r-b= -(b-r)$).
Therefore, $|a-b|$ $\leq$ $|a-r|$+$|r-b|$